# Initialize priority_queue without constructor

Tags: c++

I have a `priority_queue` with custom comparator:

```
using A = ...

class A {
public:
    A() {
        auto cmp = [](DataPair left, DataPair right) {
            return left.second > right.second;
        };
        std::priority_queue<DataPair, std::vector<DataPair>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);
        q_ = q;
    }

private:
    std::priority_queue<DataPair, std::vector<DataPair>, decltype(cmp)> q_;
};
```

Is there a way to initialize `priority_queue` without constructor ?

Comment: What's wrong about a constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `decltype(cmp)` for the member type when `cmp` is local to the constructor. You can move the definition of the comparator out of the constructor and use the [default constructor of `priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) which default constructs the comparator:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const DataPair& left,const DataPair& right) {
        return left.second > right.second;
    }
};

class A {
public:

private:
    std::priority_queue<DataPair, std::vector<DataPair>, cmp> q_;
};
```

Comment: Bump. Note: `cmp` *can* be a nested class within `A` and this will still work, but without cluttering the global namespace.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think in C++20 one could even use `decltype([](const auto& left,const auto& right){.....}` for the template argument to have it all inline